# Term store management link invisible to Site Owner

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, administration, term-store

I am owner [ assigned through site owners group] of sub site in a site collection, But I didn't find Term store management link in site administration settings, where us site collection administrator has able to see the link. I can access directly the link [ to browse the link] but I need it in site administration settings that helpful to my fellow site administrators. Please anyone knows this kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

A hidden web application feature is probably not activated.

Solution:

You can activate it through PowerShell or stsadm:

```
Enable-SPFeature -id “73EF14B1-13A9-416b-A9B5-ECECA2B0604C” -Url <SiteCollection-URL>

Stsadm.exe -o activatefeature -id 73EF14B1-13A9-416b-A9B5-ECECA2B0604C –url http://<SiteCollection-URL> –force
```

Comment: HI Ruslan, I tried above and it says the feature is already activated in scope. I know this because of the link is visible to site collection administrator where us not visible for user in site owners group.